# Add class on click to a path with leaflet js

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I am trying to add a class to the clicked polygon using:

```
function addClass() {
    function style(feature) {
        return {
            className: "active"
        };
    }
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click: addClass
    });
}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLeXKX)

[Docs here](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path)

Comment: Please provide a working example (jsfiddle/codepen/snippet)

Comment: added the jsfiddle in the question.

Comment: Check the console for errors. `Uncaught ReferenceError: statesData is not defined(…)`

Comment: jsfiddle is requesting files in http while it is on https, can't load the files in

Comment: @Dekel updated with codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `app` in your code only creates a function (and nothing more). This function is only created, but never fired.
Another problem is that this function does nothing that relevant to the element that was clicked.

Here is the change you are looking for:

```
function app(e) {
    this.getElement().classList.add('active')
}
```

Here is a working codepen (based on your code):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEmMRE

> I added the `active` class to the CSS so you can actually see the change on the screen

Comment: Sure :) You are welcome. A voteup will also be nice :)